# Populate Table with Table Rows and Cells on LinkButton click event while getting info from XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, tablerow

Basically I create Rows then Cells then i populate the Cells with LinkButton which is getting Text value  from XML nodes .

Code :

```
 private void linkBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
                string text = btn.Text.ToString();
                XmlDocument clickDoc = new XmlDocument();
                clickDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ProductShow.xml"));
                XmlNodeList btnNode = clickDoc.SelectNodes("products/" + text.ToString() + "/*");
                int count = btnNode.Count;


                foreach (XmlNode node in btnNode)
                {


                   TableRow row = new TableRow();

                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.CssClass = "Cell";

                    LinkButton linkbtn = new LinkButton();
                    linkbtn.Text = node.InnerText;
                    linkbtn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    Image img = new Image();

                    cell.Controls.Add(linkbtn);
                    cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
                    cell.Controls.Add(img);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    MainTable.Rows.Add(row);


                }







    }
```

My problem is that i want to create 4 cells for each row  and my code creates 1 cell for each row untill the Nodes end

Comment: Where is your MainTable object defined?

Comment: in the Default.aspx inside UpdatePanel  .. Content

Answer (score 0):

You need another loop to add more columns to each row

```
 foreach (XmlNode node in btnNode)
    {
       TableRow row = new TableRow();

       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.CssClass = "Cell";

                LinkButton linkbtn = new LinkButton();
                linkbtn.Text = node.InnerText;
                linkbtn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                Image img = new Image();

                cell.Controls.Add(linkbtn);
                cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
                cell.Controls.Add(img);

                row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
                MainTable.Rows.Add(row);                  
   }
```

Comment: but this will override the btnNode content for example if in btnNode nodes are five

this loop will make 

first row with [0] [1] [2] [3]

second row will be [1] [2] [3][4]

and so on i would like it to be 

[0][1][2][3]

[4][5][6][7]
.....

Comment: I'm confused I thought you said you said you wanted to create 4 columns/cells are you now saying you want a cell for each node? And also a row for each node? you lost me...

Comment: no i want 4 cells for each row your example works but it overwrites the  value of nodes within the btnNode.


It will make Rows  with 4 Cells which have 4 LinkButtons with exactly the same Text and i dont want this